# Do we have OData Connector for Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, odata

If OData Services are implemented over any database, do we have Apache Spark Connector to connect with OData services to consume the data ?

Comment: In general the connector which Cdata provides hits their API , wanted to know if there are any other connectors between spark and Odata Services  - Apache spark being the consumer for Odata services in this case

Comment: I am also looking for spark connector for odata service, do you find any?